# not able to load angular-mocks.js in karma and protractor for testing

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, protractor, karma-runner

I'm trying to load angular-mocks into my testing env. but I'm running into issues. I have my karma config like so...

```
        'angular/angular/angular.js',
        'angular/angular-mocks.js',
        'angular/angular/angular-animate.js'
```

but it does not seem to pick up angular-mocks.js. when i load angular-mocks in my index.html file like so my tests pass  fine which utilize ngMockE2E and $httpBackend (i want to avoid hard coding it in my index.html)...

```
<script src="/angular/angular-mocks.js"></script>
```

i have tried doing this also in protractor config, but then i get window not defined error...

```
onPrepare: function () {
    require("angular-mocks");
}
```

do i need to initialize something in my beforeEach function to get angular-mocks to load? any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

In protractor, a built-in way to mock things during testing is to use [`addMockModule()`](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=Protractor.prototype.addMockModule) function:

```
browser.addMockModule('modName', function() {
  angular.module('modName', []).value('foo', 'bar');
});
```